# Access S3 CSV file in Amazon Athena

Tags: amazon-web-services, csv, amazon-s3, amazon-athena

I am trying to load a files from s3 to Athena to perform a query operation. But all the column values are getting added to the first column.

I have file in the following format:

```
id,user_id,personal_id,created_at,updated_at,active
34,34,43,31:28.4,27:07.9,TRUE
```

This is the output I get:

[image]

Table creation query:

```
   CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `testing`(
      `id` string, 
      `user_id` string, 
      `personal_id` string, 
      `created_at` string, 
      `updated_at` string, 
      `active` string)
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 
      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
    STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
      'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
    OUTPUTFORMAT 
      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
    LOCATION
      's3://testing2fa/'
    TBLPROPERTIES (
      'transient_lastDdlTime'='1665356861')
```

Please can someone tell me where am I going wrong?

Comment: Please do not provide screenshot of excel or other spreadsheet software. Please provide actual csv data as it is written in csv file, not its spreadsheet.

Comment: @Marcin have attached the SS file from editor

Answer (score 1):

You should add `skip.header.line.count` to your table properties to skip the first row. As you have defined all columns as string data type Athena was unable to differentiate between header and first row.

DDL with property added:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `testing`(
      `id` string, 
      `user_id` string, 
      `personal_id` string, 
      `created_at` string, 
      `updated_at` string, 
      `active` string)
    ROW FORMAT SERDE 
      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
    STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
      'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
    OUTPUTFORMAT 
      'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
    LOCATION
      's3://testing2fa/'
    TBLPROPERTIES ('skip.header.line.count'='1')
```

Answer (score 1):

The Serde needs some parameter to recognize CSV files, such as:

```sql
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
      FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
      ESCAPED BY '\\'
      LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
```

See: [LazySimpleSerDe for CSV, TSV, and custom-delimited files - Amazon Athena](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/lazy-simple-serde.html)

An alternative method is to **use AWS Glue to create the tables for you**. In the AWS Glue console, you can **create a Crawler** and point it to your data. When you run the crawler, it will automatically create a table definition in Amazon Athena that matches the supplied data files.